# Solving equation with one variable

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, equation

In the following code i am trying to find value of `Teq` inside the function `B(x,Teq)`. 
I just have to note that the code is correct, the whole for loops and etc. But I just added the part of `solve equation` and it does not works just shows me `[] [] [] [] [] [] [] ....`
I do not understand whay I ma getting this.

how to do that.

any help please?

```
dfimppara = pd.read_csv('C:/Users....csv', sep=",")
dfimporto = pd.read_csv('C:/Users....csv', sep=",")
dfpara=dfimppara.values
dforto=dfimporto.values
Tpara=dfpara[0,4:len(dfpara[0,:])]
Torto=dforto[0,4:len(dforto[0,:])]
Jup  = dfpara[:,1]
Jlw = dfpara[:,2]
def B(x,Teq):
    ee = exp(h * (dfimppara.iloc[x, 1] * 115e9)/ (KB * Teq)) - 1
    return ((2 * h * ((dfimppara.iloc[x, 1] * 115e9 ) ** 3)/c**2) * (ee**(-1)))

def Unu(x,z,test):
    TCMB = 2.7 * (1 + z)
    ee = exp(h * (dfimppara.iloc[x, 1] * 115e9)/ (KB * TCMB)) - 1
    return ((8 * pi * h * ((dfimppara.iloc[x, 1] * 115e9 ) ** 3)/c**3) * pow(ee, -1)) * test

from sympy import Symbol, Eq, solve
UU=[1e-25,1e-24,1e-23,1e-22,1e-21,1e-20,1e-19]
for ng in np.arange(100,200,500):
    for z in np.arange(1, 2):
        for xx in range(1, 819):
            for uff in range (len(UU)): 
                Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                lim = Ju - Jl
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    if Ju<2:
                        Teq = Symbol('Teq')
                        an = solve(UU[uff] + Unu(xx,z,1) - B(xx,Teq), 0)
                        print(an)
                    else:
                        pass
```

Comment: please add a minimal example for `dfimppara`

Comment: You are mixing numpy and sympy, what generally is a bad idea. Sympy can not work with numpy functions, and numpy doesn't understand about sympy symbols.

Comment: @JohanC Ah really? So what should I do to solve the equation then :(

Comment: @MaY: please show how dfimppara looks like. Don't read it from an unavailable file.  Just create a small example with some typical constants.

Comment: @MaY: You might try to solve it with one of numpy's solvers. By the way, `np.arange(100,200,500)` is just one value (from 100 to 200 step 500). Maybe you intended to use np.linspace. Similarly, `np.arange(1,2)` is just the number 1.

Comment: @JohanC we have no `ng` in this code, I forgot to remove it. I could not find the numpy solver on the net

Comment: There are many https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html